# "All executable devices in the domain are busy"

Tags: redhawksdr

When I try to run a very simple waveform from the command line, I get the error shown below.
 I'm running something incredibly simple, and there is no way the GPP is completely utilized.
 Load is `.04` on a `2 core machine` without the waveform running.

This is a somewhat random error. Sometimes it works, usually it does not.

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/ossie/utils/redhawk/core.py", line 1793, in createApplication
    app = app_factory.create(name, initConfiguration, [])
  File "/usr/local/redhawk/core/lib/python/ossie/cf/cf_idl.py", line 2026, in create
    return _omnipy.invoke(self, "create", _0_CF.ApplicationFactory._d_create, args)
ossie.cf.CF.CreateApplicationError: CF.ApplicationFactory.CreateApplicationError(errorNumber=CF_ENOSPC, msg="Unable to launch component 'add_constant'. All executable devices (i.e.: GPP) in the Domain are busy")
```

Answer (score 0):

The default settings for the GPP are for a multi core machine. For limited CPU resource machines, you can change the following settings to ignore the idle setting calculations.

reservered_capacity_per_component=0

thresholds:
       cpu_idle = 0